# Android: Implementing a synchronous/blocking API using Messengers for IPC

Tags: java, android, ipc, android-handler

I have a background service that runs in its own separate process using

```
android:process=":deamon"
```

In the manifest entry for the service. I want to communicate with the the service (remote process) from my activity and receive data from it.
I'm doing that by sending messages to and from the remote process as described in http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger and as they suggested I followed

> If you want the service to respond, then you need to also create a Messenger in the client. >Then when the client receives the onServiceConnected() callback, it sends a Message to the >service that includes the client's Messenger in the replyTo parameter of the send() method.

The thing is, I need to provide a blocking/synchronous API to get data from my remote service, how can my "get" function block the caller and then return the data received in my incoming Handler ?
What would be the best approach to do that ?

Comment: You should give a try to AIDL, you define the methods and just call, everything is sync and no more trouble on defining protocols http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: I had and "anti" feeling about aidl but now I will it a peek

Comment: Thanks, its clearly a much better approch

Answer (score 3):

This is code for messaging part of Client

```
    SparseArray<CountDownLatch> lockArray = new SparseArray<>();
    SparseArray<Bundle> msgDataArray = new SparseArray<>();

    public Bundle sendAndWaitResponse(Message msg) throws 
                                RemoteException, InterruptedException {
        int msgId = msg.arg2;
        Log.d("PlatformConnector", "Sending message to service, Type: "
                                 + msg.what + ", msgId: " + msg.arg2);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        lockArray.put(msgId, latch);
        platformMessenger.send(msg);
        latch.await();

        Bundle response = msgDataArray.get(msgId);
        lockArray.delete(msgId);
        msgDataArray.delete(msgId);

        return response;
    }

    void storeResponseAndNotify(Message msg) {
        int msgId = msg.arg2;
        // Because the message itself is recycled after Handler returns,
        // we should store only the data of message
        msgDataArray.put(msgId, msg.getData());
        lockArray.get(msgId).countDown();
    }


    private class ClientMessageHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            storeResponseAndNotify(msg);
        }
    }
```

This is example of utilizing above code.
`RandomInt.getNextInt()` is my custom static method, which generates random integer with `Random.nextInt()`.

```
    public JSONObject doSomething(JSONObject object) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, Constants.MESSAGE_SOMETHING, 0, RandomInt.getNextInt());
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.MESSAGE_DATA_SOMETHING, object.toString());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        try {
            Bundle responseData = sendAndWaitResponse(msg);
            return new JSONObject(responseData.getString(Constants.MESSAGE_DATA_RETURN));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send message to platform");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Interrupted while waiting message from platform");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Sequence is as follows,

1. The Client prepares `Message` and set its `arg2` as some random integer
   (this integer will be the message id for synchronization).
2. The Client prepares new `CountDownLatch` and put it to `LockArray`.
3. the Client sends message with `sendAndWaitResponse()`. It sends message to service via `Messenger` and invokes `latch.await()`.
4. Service processes receives message and prepare reply message. The `arg2` of this reply message should be same as received message.
5. Service sends reply message to client via `Messenger` in replyTo.
6. Client message handler handles the message with `storeResponseAndNotify`.
7. When the blocking of Client thread is finished, the response data would be already prepared in `msgDataArray`.

`CountDownLatch` is simple switch to block and unblock the thread.
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

`SparseArray` is similar to `HashMap`, but more memory-efficient for smaller sets.
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)

Be careful not to block the thread of `Messenger`. `Messenger` runs in single thread and if you block from the `handleMessage()`, it will block all other messages and cause deaklock problem.

Comment: Good one.  Perhaps you can avoid the sparse array of messages awaiting answers, because the documentation says that the messages received by the service messenger are queued; you could more simply set up a synchronized queue of responses. 
"[Messenger] is the simplest way to perform interprocess communication (IPC), because the Messenger queues all requests into a single thread so that you don't have to design your service to be thread-safe." https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html